# Laravel - AngularJS ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

I know angularjs does not need jquery lib .
I have created laravel project with default auth so I was thinking to use angularjs as front end in the laravel view of registration so on conform password I have created angularjs directive for password searched from google.
Now, when every thing is in place all is well but when I remove jquery lib from master page it give me this -

1. it is a bootstrap error
2. it is a angularjs error which i didn't unterstand 
   please help.

ok so my console is

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery bootstrap.min.js:6

ReferenceError: $ is not defined angular.js:11500
```

but then when I add jquery lib all is well how so ?
and also how to make bootstrap in laravel now to give error without adding jquery lib.

Comment: be sure jquery loading before bootsrap.min,js

Comment: ok when is do that every this run smooth but when is remove the file just to test angularjs it give the error so does angularjs required jquery lib.

Comment: load jquery top of page before other javascipts

Comment: so angularjs need jquery lib, Thanks since i am new to angularjs